# Simple Textual Link for sharing on Facebook, Linkedin, Twitter and Google+ WITHOUT a company account

Tags: facebook, twitter, google-plus, linkedin-api, social-networking

A company (**without** any promotional facebook, Linkedin, googleplus or twitter account) needs a simple clean custom sharing link text button for their page `www.company.net/projectX` so people can share and link to the page with a single click like so:

```
Share this project on:  f | in | t | g+

<a href="...">f</a>
<a href="...">in</a>
<a href="...">t</a>
<a href="...">g+</a>
```

What are ways to do this simply (remember the company has no social accounts themselves)

This is one solution provided by a contributor: https://github.com/bradvin/social-share-urls

1.Why are all urls "encoded"? In that way the shared pages dont get higher rankings on search engines right?

2.I assume the generator.htm is not necessary in that package? Just the javascript script (which can be stripped to only those needed?)

3.When I add `<a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u={www.company.net/projectX}">Share this project</a>` in the body and script `<script src="share/generator.js"></script>` and `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="share/font.css">`
 in the head, then the link is invisible and nothing happens.

Comment: 1. Because they are put into another URL as a parameter value, so naturally they _need_ to be encoded. 2. I was actually referring to this github page as an explanation how you can build those simple URL share links yourself (because that seemed to be what you were asking); I have not tried to use the script it is offering.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/bradvin/social-share-urls has a list of simple share URLs for many social networks.